# Uncaught ReferenceError: "myfunction" is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to run a function called "fn" with the onchange event, change the dropdown options. but this error to me (index): 190 Uncaught ReferenceError: fn () is not defined. Why is this happening?. I'm sure my function exists.

this is my code:

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<select id='dropdown' onchange="fn();">
 <option value='1'>data1</option>
 <option value='2'>data2</option>
 <option value='3'>data3</option>
</select>

function fn(){
 ...
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yvvxbhn3/

Comment: Do you have the declaration of `fn()` inside of a [`<script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) element?

Comment: Where is your function defined?

Comment: It is because your fiddle is set up wrong. The fiddle is set to be run onload and that means your function is NOT in global scope.

Comment: You need to pass in THIS.  ie: fn(this).  "This" points to the select statement. OR if you use jQuery you use the $("dropdown") to get what you are working with. On the THIS: the onchange="fn(this);" and the function statement is function fn(e){.  Where the "e" is for Element. :-)

Comment: @APerson you just removed the problem.... And created a new one. Fiddle was the issue.

Comment: @epascarello Oops, will revert. (And that's probably a "typographical issue" flag, then, too.)

Comment: @APerson jsFiddle not know well the page. but my role was the part where this javascript code. That's wrong?

Comment: @epascarello pardon my ignorance. I do not understand. how I can corregirlo.no I am familiar with jsdfiddle

Comment: click the gear icon beside the word javascript, change onload to head or body. Your code still has other issues, but that will clear up the issue you have.

Comment: @epascarello it works now!. thank you very much.